# Why isn't `multiple` attribute working with `select` tag as stated in the documentation?

Tags: html

[Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/select.html#select.attrs.multiple) according to documentation:

> multiple = "multiple" or "" (empty string) or empty If present,
>   indicates that its select element represents a control for selecting
>   zero or more options from a list of options. If not present, indicates
>   that its select element represents a control for selecting a single
>   option from a list of options.

As the documentation says `....represents a control for selecting zero or more options from a list of options....` why can't I select more than one options at the same time in [this](http://jsbin.com/pajuteyafu/edit?html,output) example ?

Code I am having problem with is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="display.php">
  <table width="300" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td><label>Multiple Selection </label>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
      <select name="select2" size="10" multiple="multiple" tabindex="1">
        <option value="11">eleven</option>
        <option value="12">twelve</option>
        <option value="13">thirette</option>
        <option value="14">fourteen</option>
        <option value="15">fifteen</option>
        <option value="16">sixteen</option>
        <option value="17">seventeen</option>
        <option value="18">eighteen</option>
        <option value="19">nineteen</option>
        <option value="20">twenty</option>
      </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" tabindex="2" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Also, I am using Google Chrome.**

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try either `<select name="select2" size="10" multiple="true" tabindex="1">` or just `<select name="select2" size="10" multiple tabindex="1">`

Comment: Doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Actually your example works fine.  Are you holding the Control Key down when you select the items?

Comment: The edited versions of the code in the answer are irrelevant to the problem, and the first one is even invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question is OK. It depends on the browser how multiple selections can be made when the `multiple` attribute is used. In a typical browser, hold the Ctrl key down when clicking on an option in order to select it without unselecting anything. And hold the Shift key down when clicking on an option to select all options from a previously selected option to the clicked option (and to unselect other selected options).